# Max Sum Path In Two Sorted Arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, mergesort

I am doing practice questions from geeksforgeeks. And I'm unable to solve the question and get the required output.

[https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/max-sum-path-in-two-arrays/1/?category[]=Arrays&company[]=Amazon&difficulty[]=0&page=1&sortBy=submissions&query=category[]Arrayscompany[]Amazondifficulty[]0page1sortBysubmissions](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/max-sum-path-in-two-arrays/1/?category%5B%5D=Arrays&company%5B%5D=Amazon&difficulty%5B%5D=0&page=1&sortBy=submissions&query=category%5B%5DArrayscompany%5B%5DAmazondifficulty%5B%5D0page1sortBysubmissions)

```
//I am finding the max path using the merge sort algo, where T(n)=O(m+n)
int MaxPath(int a[],int b[],int n,int m){
int i, j, result=0, sum1=0, sum2=0; // sum1 and sum2 store the sums of 1st and 2nd arrays respectively
while(i<n && j<m){
    if(a[i]<b[j]){
        sum1+=a[i++];
    }
    else if(a[i]>b[j]){
        sum2+=b[j++];
    }
    else{
        result+=Max(sum1,sum2);
        sum1=0;
        sum2=0;
        int temp=i;
        while(i<n && a[i]==b[j]){
            sum1+=a[i++];
        }
        while(j<m && a[temp]==b[j]){
            sum2+=b[j++];
        }
        result+=Max(sum1,sum2);
        sum1=0;
        sum2=0;
    }
}
while(i<n){
    sum1+=a[i++];
}
while(j<m){
    sum2+=b[j++];
}
result+=Max(sum1,sum2);
return result;
}
```

Comment: How is `Max()` defined?

Comment: @ryyker I wrote a function for that in my program.

Comment: Okay - In this case, if the uninitialized variables are the only issue, this is not an issue.  But if more issues existed it is always good to provide a [mcve], which would include the definition of `Max()`, to help those working the problem.  :)

Comment: okay, thank you @ryyker I'll definitely keep that in mind next time I post a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined behavior at beginning of code. This statement:

```
while(i<n && j<m){
```

Is called before the value of `i`, or `j` is set:

```
int i, j, result=0, sum1=0, sum2=0;
```

Note that the other items created have been set, but not `i` and `j`.

It is therefore undefined from this point on how this while loop will perform.  Initialize all variables before they are used.